# Retrieving results from Mturk Sandbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, mturk

I'm working on retrieving my HIT results from my local computer. I followed the template of `get_results.py` and entered my key_id, access_key correctly, and installed xmltodict but got the error message. Could anyone help me figure out why? Here is my HIT address if anyone needs the format of my HIT `https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=3MKP0VNPM2VVY0K5UTNZX9OO9Q8RJE`

```
    import boto3
    mturk = boto3.client('mturk',
       aws_access_key_id = "PASTE_YOUR_IAM_USER_ACCESS_KEY",
       aws_secret_access_key = "PASTE_YOUR_IAM_USER_SECRET_KEY",
       region_name='us-east-1',
       endpoint_url = MTURK_SANDBOX
    )
    # You will need the following library
    # to help parse the XML answers supplied from MTurk
    # Install it in your local environment with
    # pip install xmltodict
    import xmltodict
    # Use the hit_id previously created
    hit_id = 'PASTE_IN_YOUR_HIT_ID'
    # We are only publishing this task to one Worker
    # So we will get back an array with one item if it has been completed
    worker_results = mturk.list_assignments_for_hit(HITId=hit_id, AssignmentStatuses=['Submitted'])
```

[image]